# just_audio Package Flutter Playlist not work on Release mode

Tags: flutter, dart, package

I use just_audio package for my app, and now I face a problem with the playlist Error on release mode, I get sounds from uri.parse and worked perfectly but only the playlist does not work!

I attached an image for a better understanding, and share my code

[On Debug mode Playlist does not have issues like this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opcA1.png)

[But in release mode, it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Atnc.jpg)

I've tried it on different devices but it's the same

My Code for playlist

```
SizedBox(
            height: 240.0,
            child: StreamBuilder<SequenceState?>(
              stream: _player.sequenceStateStream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                final state = snapshot.data;
                final sequence = state?.sequence ?? [];
                return ReorderableListView(
                  onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
                    if (oldIndex < newIndex) newIndex--;
                    _playlist.move(oldIndex, newIndex);
                  },
                  children: [
                    for (var i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++)
                      Expanded(
                        key: ValueKey(sequence[i]),
                        child: Material(
                          //color with seekbar percentage color
                          color: i == state!.currentIndex
                              ? Color.fromARGB(42, 167, 24, 48)
                              : Colors.transparent,
                          child: ListTile(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                            trailing: Text(
                              (i + 1).toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                  color: i == state.currentIndex
                                      ? Color.fromARGB(255, 190, 26, 53)
                                      : Color.fromARGB(255, 58, 58, 58)),
                            ),
                            title: Text(
                              sequence[i].tag.title,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                              style: boldTextStyle(
                                  size: 16,
                                  fontFamily: 'medium',
                                  weight: FontWeight.normal,
                                  color: i == state.currentIndex
                                      ? Color.fromARGB(255, 190, 26, 53)
                                      : Color.fromARGB(255, 107, 107, 107)),
                            ),
                            leading: i == state!.currentIndex
                                ? Material(
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(230, 217, 52, 40),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    child: Container(
                                      height: 31,
                                      width: 30,
                                      child: IconButton(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                                        icon:
                                            Icon(Icons.graphic_eq_outlined),
                                        iconSize: 22,
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(
                                            255, 245, 245, 245),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          _player.pause();
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                : Material(
                                    color:
                                        Color.fromARGB(255, 227, 228, 237),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    child: Container(
                                      height: 31,
                                      width: 30,
                                      child: IconButton(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                                        icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                                        iconSize: 22,
                                        color:
                                            Color.fromARGB(255, 49, 53, 60),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          _player.pause();
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                            onTap: () {
                              _player.seek(Duration.zero, index: i);
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you get your songs from a remote source, for this you need to give your app internet permission. Internet permission is automatically set in debug mode, this is why it only works in debug.

```
<manifest xmlns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: yes I get songs from remote sources but I can fetch songs does not have a problem only the playlist didn't show like the image I attached

Comment: Can you try to run it profile mode and see if you get any errors in your console

Comment: I did and yes in profile mode I get the same error as release mode and I see this error in my console when I run it on profile mode 

Attachement Error Image : https://i.ibb.co/CsywcWK/err.png